# Windows server and interface mirroring

Tags: windows-server-2008

I need to mirror traffic from one interface of windows server 2008 to another (on which IDS snort listens).
Can I do this with standard utilities of windows server?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you set up on the host generating the traffic. "Mirroring" is typically a feature of the switch used for interconnection. You will find it in most managed and "smart managed" switch series as well as in recent virtual switch implementations in hypervisors (vSphere 5 and newer with the Enterprise license, Hyper-V 2012 and newer).

Although Windows would support basic switch-like functionality through [Network Bridging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770507%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) out of the box, it is missing the port mirror feature.

Comment: Problem is that we haven't "smart" switches (only dlink DES-1016D like stuff)
and seems like only way to install snort in this office is 
connect it to windows server gateway and setup traffic mirroring on it.

P.S.: Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: @dz_lnly This is easy then - replace the switch which is connecting your "Windows Server gateway" to the rest of the network with a model supporting port mirroring. If you want to stay with DLink, the [DGS-1210 series do have it listed as a supported feature](http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Business_Products/DGS/DGS%201210%2010P/Datasheet/DGS_1210_10_Datasheet_EN_UK.pdf).